# How to go to a page on onclick depending on combobox value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, onclick

I have a combobox and a button. When I click the button, it uses the value from the combobox and goes to another page. My question is, how do I alter it so that, if, for example, the value in the combobox is currently 6, you don't get directed to a page, but rather get a warning on the same page that you can't use value 6 from the combobox? If it's any value other than 6, it just does the same onclick function it always does. I'm also relatively new to Javascript, so that's why I can't currently wrap my head around this.

Comment: can you please go to jsbin.com and create a sample of your existing code so we have something to start with?

Comment: Or http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this HTML:

```
<select id="myCombobox"> 
    <option value="6">Value is 6</option>
    <option value="7">Value is 7</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

your javascript should be something like this

```
function myFunction(){
    var comboboxValue = document.getElementById('myCombobox').value;
    if (comboboxValue === 6){
        return false; // do nothing if combobox value is 6 
    }
    else{
        //do your redirection here
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
var mycomboboxval = document.getElementById('mycombobox').value;
var mylink = document.getElementById('mylink');

if(mycomboboxval == 6){
    mylink.href = "#";
    alert("Warning : you can't use number 6");
}else{
    mylink.href = "page.html"; //Replace page.html by the normal link href
}
```

Preview : [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBzbh)

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Thank you for the added alert. I didn't really know how to go about that part. Thanks!